# List of default method of class create by React.createClass() that I can override

Tags: react-native

By watching, reading tutorials from variable source, I already known 2 methods that I can override are getInitialState() and render(). 
I wonder are there any other methods that I can override. 
I already searched on Google but I haven't found any official document yet.
Can anybody help me ?

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
  AppRegistry,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  Image,
  Navigator,
  View
} from 'react-native';

var LessonList = React.createClass({
  getInitialState: function() {
      return {
        meow:'MeowMeow',
      };
    },
  render:function(){
    return(
      <Text>
        Keep Calm and Meow On !!!
      </Text>
    );
  }
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

List available in [Component Specs](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-specs.html) in React docs.